# Volley library SSL error

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, android-volley

I am using the Volley library and I get this error link https is working when I remove SSL but I want to use with SSL

```
    error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported 
protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x74ac5d5c:0x00000000)
```

Comment: You will need to show your code and which URL you target. Did you try your code with another URL ? Did you try another client on the same URL ? These are all trivial steps to troubleshoot...

Comment: what is the ssl version on your server side?

Comment: how can I learn ssl version ?